# Why is this supposedly dashed line showing up as solid in the Windows Forms .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework

The following code occurs inside the System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler of a System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox under the .NET Compact Framework (e is of type PaintEventArgs):

```
var penDashed = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
penDashed.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
using (penDashed)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(penDashed, 30, 30, 100, 30);
}
```

The line is rendering solid in spite of the fact I've set the DashStyle to Dashed. The length and color are just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is should work as it is supposed to. I wonder why you declare and modify the Pen outside of the using clause though. That looks wrong to me.. `using (Pen penDashed = new Pen(Color.Red, 3)) { penDashed.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash; e.Graphics.DrawLine(penDashed, 30, 30, 100, 30);}` would be how I write this..

Comment: The reason it's declared as such is that I'm following the style already present in the inherited code. It's actually drawing rectangles that are solid (using Graphics.DrawPolygon()). I'm trying to add a dashed rectangle to the mix. The dashed rectangle was rendering as solid so I tried something simpler like a line and got the same result.

Comment: The width of the pen causes the dashes to touch eachother. If you draw a line with a pen width of 1, the dash appears again. I don't know if there is any straightforward way of getting the desired result.

Comment: This should not happen! Testing in Winforms the gaps betwenn the dashes are in fact __growing__ with the pen.width, actually always staying equal to Pen.width with DashCap=Flat

Comment: I don't know about the Compact Framework but in Winforms using  `pen.DashCap = DashCap.Triangle;`will make the gap look a little larger. the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk68eecs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) doesn't say it is upported under CF

Comment: @TaW:  Actually, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx DashCap is not available in the compact framework.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid so. Did you try playing with the Pen.Width?

Comment: Just tried it. And sure enough, C.Evenhuis is correct. By going to a width of 1, it works. I think the customer will be fine with the dashed rectangle being slightly narrower than the solid version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927220.aspx) (for the Windows API, not specifically for the compact framework) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927220.aspx):

> Windows CE supports wide pens and dashed pens, but **does not** support dotted pens, inside frame pens, geometric pens, pen endcap styles, **or pens that are both wide and dashed**.

Comment: Thanks for this. (And bringing back bad memories of working with Hungarian notation. :) ) Sure enough, by dropping the width to 1, which is mentioned in the documentation to which you linked as the default pen width for CE, the dashes appear again.

It would have been nice for MS to have included this somewhere easily accessible in the .NET documentation.